# Big-Theta(n) linear sorting algorithm?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Design a linear algorithm to rearrange the elements of a given array of n elements so that all its negative numbers precede any zeroes, and any zeroes precede any positive numbers. It should also be space efficient so that it doesn't require more than a constant amount of additional space.

Everything I am thinking of is much bigger than `O(n)`, and would love some tips/hints/help/java code!

Comment: are you interested to sort all items , or rearrange only for 3 ranges negative, zero and positive (without a sort in the range it self)?

Comment: yes, just a rearrange... I guess I shouldn't have put "sorting" in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help? Hint: Quicksort's partition part with pivot as `0`. [See this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), look for in-place version.

---

I just realized if you implement teh exact version given in the link above it may not help if you have dupes of zero. My statement is still true that you need to use partition part of Quicksort, but the partition is going to be done by [Dutch National Flag problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) or three way partitioning. Here is the pseudo code for you

```
//assume index based 1
A[1..n]
p = 0
q = n+1
i = 1

while i < q
  if A[i] < 0
   swap(i, ++p)
  else if A[i] > 0
   swap(i, --q)
  else
   i++
```

Time complexity:    `O(n)`
Space complexity: `O(1)`

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered by clicking on the up-tick next to this answer. [See here how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you liked the answer, you may also up-vote by clicking on up arrow next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using a modified version of Radix Sort, the only sorts that can work in linear time are non-comparison based sorts (so entries in the list/array are not compared to each other) so that's something else to look at (proof involves comparison trees of minimum height as to why a sort that compares items will always be at least nlogn).

Comment: -1, I believe that your suggestion will require more then constant amount of additional space, Additionally , you suggest a sorting algorithm, here OP didn't request a sort but a very simple rearrange of items based on 3 values, will happy to Upvote if you explain where i am mistaken.

Comment: @Michael Radix based sort with an index array of size 3 (negative, positive, zero) uses constant space (integer array of size 3). Sorting takes 2 passes over the inital array.

Comment: 3 cells is nice , but what are you holding inside the cells, by not constant i meant exactly this???

Comment: @Michael It's an index counter, 1 for negative numbers, 1 for zeroes, and 1 for positive numbers. It acts the same as the normal index array for standard radix sort.

Comment: (please edit your answer so that i will be able to upvote back), although you don't need a radix sort to count the indexes with a single iteration.

Comment: @Michael That's true, I just mentioned it for him as a way to think about it or have some code that can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you require only the rearrangement of items according to 3 ranges , negative zero and positive.

An easy solution will be count the number of negative, zeros and positives items with single array iteration (O(n))  (actually you don't need to count the number of positives if you already know the size of the array).

with a second iteration you will swap items (starting from the first one) according to their range to the appropriate index , then increase the index.

That's it, no additional memory and teta(n) time complexity.